# How do I get the basic chat Scala/Lift application to run?

Tags: scala, lift

I'm following the tutorial here

http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-2.html

So far I have created a directory, and pasted the source code into text files.  I then copied sbt.bat and sbt-launcher.jar into the directory.  Upon running

sbt update ~jetty-run

I get the following error message

"No action named 'jetty-run' exists"

Comment: What version of SBT are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Never having run Lift, I'm uniquely unqualified to answer this question.  However, I **am** an SBT user, so....
Try running these two commands from the sbt command line.  First get into sbt:
sbt <enter>
then type: 
update<enter>
that will likely take a very long time to complete.  When it finishes, type 
~jetty-run<enter>
which should build any bits of Lift that need it and launch Jetty with Lift deployed.  If all goes well, commence chatting.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't jetty dependency in your config file or it wasn't successfully fetched.

Steps to launch chat app:

Clone sbt project from github
`$git clone git://github.com/dpp/simply_lift.git`

Launch sbt
`$cd simply_lift/chat`
`$./sbt`
Scala library will be downloaded.

From sbt console
`> update`
This will fetch all dependencies from sbt config file (project/build/LiftProject.scala). Make sure that all dependencies were downloaded successfully.

And finally
`> jetty-run`